# Edit Name of cell upon tap - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to edit the text in a cell by tapping and I was wondering if there is a way to do it other than by adding a text field. is there something  in the table view delegate that I missed?

Comment: you pretty much have to add a text field. the whole thing is much harder than it is made to look in "simple examples".  you'll definitely need a custom UITableViewCell class, to begin with  :/

Comment: making a custom cell with a textField is probably the best way.

Comment: I Found this apple doc : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html   but How would I do this in swift? this insert part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create cell (or any other UIResponder subclass) that conforms UITextInput protocol (or maybe UIKeyInput is enough). Here is simple [example](https://github.com/jogu/SimpleTextInput) ([old link](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/SimpleTextInput/Introduction/Intro.html.))

Notice,

- you should set `cell.canBecomeFirstResponder = true`.
- To show keyboard use `cell.becomeFirstResponder()`

Maybe there something else, that you should do. I recommend reading docs.

...Or use UITextField :)

Answer (score 1):

We use an array to display no of text label in cell.
so you can do is, you can use a text field and a button on a view.
In button action add a line of code like `stringArray[2] = "new string"` to replace the particular element from array and when you enter a text and press a button the element will get replaced and just reload the table view.
And you can also write the method in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, write `stringArray[indexPath.row] = "new string"` and reload the table view and it is done.

Comment: This would work but I also have to be able to click on the cell to go to the next view

Comment: @ Mikael Weiss : Than write a function of changing string and call it using **NSNotification**. So when you select a row, it will send a notification and will navigate to other view controller..   Or write a string changing code and navigating or presentingViewController code in same function and just call it using **NSNotification**  in `didSelectRow` method..